# Backup of directory

Tags: java, file

I'm a student that have been learning java for the last year.

I have recently created a little program that creates a backup of a directory (it creates a directory named backup0 and copies all files of the original directory), if there's already a folder named backup0 it needs to create one folder with a different number,backup1.

I am asking those who are more advanced programmers to help me with implementing programming techniques, better organization,  etc. Pretty much anything that will help me become a better programmer.

Also, any extra tips for my future projects would be much appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;

public class Backup {


    public static void copy(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation) throws IOException {
        if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
            copyDirectory(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
        } else {
            copyFile(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
        }
    }

    private static void copyDirectory(File source, File target) throws IOException {
        if (!target.exists()) {
            target.mkdir();
        }

        for (String f : source.list()) {
            copy(new File(source, f), new File(target, f));

        }
    }

    private static void copyFile(File source, File target) throws IOException {

        if (!source.canRead()){
            System.out.printf("El archivo %s no tiene los permisos adecuados \n", source.getName());

        }else {

            try (
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target)
            ) {

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, length);

                }

            }
        }
    }

    private static int nextBackupNumber(File target) {
        int number = -1;


        File[] arxius = target.listFiles();
        for (File file : arxius) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                String nombre = file.getName();

                if (nombre.matches("^(backUp[0-9]+)")) {
                    String nBackUp = nombre.substring(6, nombre.length());

                    int number2 = Integer.parseInt(nBackUp);
                    if (number < number2) {
                        number = number2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return number + 1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String source = "src/UF5/llistes";
        File sourceLocation = new File(source);
        String target = "backUp";
        String direct = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File file = new File(direct);
        int number = nextBackupNumber(file);
        System.out.println(file);
        File targetLocation = new File(target + number);

        copy(sourceLocation, targetLocation);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Soo .. Why are you not using the library? There's `Files.copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...)` that does what you have in `copy`. The next great simplification step is in using `Files.walk`, that just traverses a directory tree.

We could attempt to simplify `copy` as follows then:

> ```
> public static void copy(Path sourceLocation, Path targetLocation)
>   throws IOException {
>     try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(sourceLocation)) {
>         files
>             .forEach(file -> {
>                 Path relative = sourceLocation.relativize(file);
>                 Files.copy(file, targetLocation.resolve(relative));
>             });
>     }
> }
> ```

But that isn't guaranteed to work, for one special reason. Checking the javadoc we can see that `Files.walk` will return the `Path` instances it visits in "Depth First Order". Because of that we'd need to either skip directories (because copy fails with an Exception when the target already exists), or use a different method.

Reading the [javadoc of `Files.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) points us to the right usecase:

> This method can be used with the [`walkFileTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) method to copy a directory and all entries in the directory, or an entire file-tree where required.

Following the link to `walkFileTree` link, we go on to `FileVisitor` and see that the exact usecase you have here, is already covered there:

> ```
>  final Path source = ...
>  final Path target = ...
>
>  Files.walkFileTree(source, EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS), Integer.MAX_VALUE,
>      new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
>          @Override
>          public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
>              throws IOException
>          {
>              Path targetdir = target.resolve(source.relativize(dir));
>              try {
>                  Files.copy(dir, targetdir);
>              } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
>                   if (!Files.isDirectory(targetdir))
>                       throw e;
>              }
>              return CONTINUE;
>          }
>          @Override
>          public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
>              throws IOException
>          {
>              Files.copy(file, target.resolve(source.relativize(file)));
>              return CONTINUE;
>          }
>      });
> ```

^^ there you are, that's your `copy` method :)

---

Now we can visit `nextBackupNumber` and `main`.

Given that we have introduced a new way to check through paths, we can simplify `nextBackupNumber` like so:

```
private static int nextBackupNumber(Path target) {
    try (Stream<Path> directories = Files.find(target, 1
      , (path, attrs) -> Files.isDirectory(path) && path.getFileName().matches("backUp\\d+"))) {
        return directories.map(dir -> {
            String dirName = dir.getFileName();
            String numberSpecifier = dirName.substring("backUp".length());
            return Integer.parseInt(numberSpecifier);
        }).max()
        .orElse(-1) + 1;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note above that I replaced the "magic number" `6` with an expression that properly conveys the meaning behind it. I also replaced `[0-9]` with it's shorthand specifier `\d` (for digit). Additionally `matches` will already anchor the regular expression, accordingly the leading `^` was not necessary.

Last but not least:

- Consider extracting `"backUp"` into a constant.
- The main-method seems somewhat complicated we can simplify it a bit:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      final String source = "src/UFS/llistes";
      final Path sourceLocation = Paths.get(source);
      final Path backupDirectory = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
      final Path backupTarget = backupDirectory.resolve(BACKUP + nextBackupNumber(backupDirectory));

      copy(sourceLocation, backupTarget);
  }
  ```

  This condenses some of the steps you do into less intermediate variables.

---

Final words:

This code is very cleanly written, and pretty easy to read and understand. For me personally it's a tad too "slow-paced" but that's something that comes with a lot of experience.

You should be looking into the Library some more. I'd especially recommend avoiding `File` and using the `Path`-related APIs significantly more.

Also note that I'm using a lot of java 8 here, which you should get comfortable with, considering that java 9 has been released already and java 7 is to be outdated soon enough.